# удаление дублей из большой mysql базы

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! есть табличка mysql с 60 млн записями, имеет поля: ID, keyword (varchar 200), cat. Необходимо оставить только записи с уникальными значениями поля "keyword", а дубликаты удалить.
Нашёл в ответах следующее решение:

> DELETE FROM keywords USING keywords, keywords t1 WHERE keywords.id >
>   t1.id AND keywords.keyword = t1.keyword

Запустил через консоль mysql, висит уже несколько часов и не знаю, сколько еще будет висеть..
Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: А сколько строк вы ожидаете получить после запроса ? Если дублей мало - то индекс по полю keyword должен помочь. Если же дублей много и в итоге должно остаться не много записей, возможно, более эффективным было бы создать другую таблицу и вставить в нее уникальные значения после чего удалить исходную и переименовать новую

Comment: Предполагаю, что уникальных записей там не более 10-15 млн. Поле "keyword" проиндексировано. А как вставить в новую таблицу уникальную значения из имеющейся?

Comment: выбрать через `distinct`?

Comment: `висит уже несколько часов и не знаю, сколько еще будет висеть..` ай, долго... это ж сколько пар надо проверить - даже если индексы юзать... сымай процесс, не дождёсься. На порядки быстрее будет скопировать данные в новую таблицу, где индекс по этому полю уникальный, а дубликаты игнорируются.

Comment: Если вам надо 80% таблицы удалить, не задумывайтесь - убейте сессию и делайте как @Mike советует.

Comment: Akina, подскажите, как это сделать, пожалуйста. Сначала создать таблицу, где поле "keyword" unique, что делать после этого?

Comment: Кажется все еще проще ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647058/removing-duplicates-with-unique-index

Comment: Как показывает практический опыт, связка `CREATE - INSERT IGNORE -
 DROP - ALTER RENAME` на реально большой таблице выполняется быстрее, чем одиночная `ALTER IGNORE`.

Comment: Запустил копирование данных в таблицу с уникальных полем. Процесс пошёл, отпишусь как отработает.